# Can I set not null clause in all columns without specifying not null clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Can I set not null clause in all columns without specifying not null clause at the time of creation?

Does a setting exist to configure this for the entire database or SQL Server instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For T-SQL: [`SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF {ON | OFF}`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187356.aspx)

> Alters the behavior of the session to override default nullability of new columns when the ANSI null default option for the database is true.
>
> This setting only affects the nullability of new columns when the nullability of the column is not specified in the CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements. By default, when SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF is ON, new columns that are created by using the ALTER TABLE and CREATE TABLE statements are NOT NULL if the nullability status of the column is not explicitly specified. SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF does not affect columns that are created by using an explicit NULL or NOT NULL.